# Capturing a specific url site in android webview, captured image is duplicated

Tags: android, webview, screen, capture

I want to capture [this site](http://m.daum.net.) in android webview

Capture code is

```
webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap webBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getDrawingCache());
webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

A captured image is overlapped. I doubt html5 css -webkit-transform attribute.

Comment: What is your problem? What exactly you need to capture?

Comment: When capturing this site, captured image is overlapped. I doubt that this site use html5 css attributes for example -webkit-rotateY, -webkit-transform. I don't know why dumped image is overlapped. Please let me know